# How to make Image pop up when my ball hits STRIKE or SPARE?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello guys here I am trying to make a bowling game. What I want is to pop up image of Strike when ball hits strike or spare image when hits spare.
please help me out your help will be appreciated.
please answer me as soon as possible.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ScoreDisplay : MonoBehaviour {

public  Image strick;
public Text[] rollTexts, frameTexts;



public void FillRolls (List<int> rolls) {
    string scoresString = FormatRolls (rolls);
    for (int i = 0; i < scoresString.Length; i++) {
        rollTexts[i].text = scoresString[i].ToString();
    }
}

public void FillFrames (List<int> frames) {
    for (int i = 0; i < frames.Count; i++) {
        frameTexts[i].text = frames[i].ToString();
    }
}

public static string FormatRolls (List<int> rolls) {
    string output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rolls.Count; i++) {
        int box = output.Length + 1;                            // Score box 1 to 21 

        if (rolls[i] == 0) {                                    // Always enter 0 as -
            output += "-";
            strick.enabled = true;
            Debug.LogError("Better Luck Next Time");
        } else if (box % 2 == 0 && rolls[i-1]+rolls[i] == 10) { // SPARE anywhere
            output += "/";  
            Debug.LogError("Its Spare");
        } else if (box >= 19 && rolls[i] == 10) {               // STRIKE in frame 10
            output += "X";
            Debug.LogError("Congo you got Strick");
        } else if (rolls[i] == 10) {                            // STRIKE in frame 1-9
            output += "X ";
            Debug.LogError("Its Strick");
        } else {
            output += rolls[i].ToString();                      // Normal 1-9 bowl
            Debug.LogError("Try Your Hard");
        }
    }

    return output;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put the image as a child of an empty `gameobject`,
this will turn it into a `gameObject` which you can easily instantiate in your code using the `Instantiate(object,position,rotation)` function. 
You can declare a public `GameObject`, drag your prefab (`Gameobject` with your image as child) into the inspector then use `Instantiate` on it, I recommend doing this because then you have more control over your `gameobject` after it's been instantiated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rolls.Count; i++) {
    int box = output.Length + 1;                            // Score box 1 to 21 

    if (rolls[i] == 0) {                                    // Always enter 0 as -
        output += "-";
        Instantiate(GameObjectYouWantToInstantiate, location, rotation);  

        //strick.enabled = true;
        Debug.LogError("Better Luck Next Time");
    } else if (box % 2 == 0 && rolls[i-1]+rolls[i] == 10) { // SPARE anywhere
        output += "/";  
        Debug.LogError("Its Spare");
    } else if (box >= 19 && rolls[i] == 10) {               // STRIKE in frame 10
        output += "X";
        Debug.LogError("Congo you got Strick");
    } else if (rolls[i] == 10) {                            // STRIKE in frame 1-9
        output += "X ";
        Debug.LogError("Its Strick");
    } else {
        output += rolls[i].ToString();                      // Normal 1-9 bowl
        Debug.LogError("Try Your Hard");
    }
}
```

Use `Destroy(Strick)` when you want to destroy it.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have tried this one also but i am getting a error of non-static member have a look

Comment: Thanks for your help I have tried this one also but i am getting a error of non-static member have a look

Error: 
Assets/Scripts/ScoreDisplay.cs(35,45): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `ScoreDisplay.strike'
Assets/Scripts/ScoreDisplay.cs(35,33): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(UnityEngine.Object, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Quaternion)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/Scripts/ScoreDisplay.cs(35,33): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Object'

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late reply, my bad. Umm, you should declare the GameObject in the body of your script, make it public, and drag your prefab into the inspector. I will upload screenshots. 
http://prntscr.com/97kx1l http://prntscr.com/97kx51

Comment: No Problem sir. I am getting your point and doing it in a same way then also its giving me the same error I guess the problem is the declare GameObject is non-static and in other hand when I declare it Public static GameObject strike; then this declaration is not a public. I there any other way to do this

Comment: There is one problem that my method is static string type which is not taking non-static variable or method. is there is any other way to do this.
The same thing i have tried in other example which is working properly.

Comment: Okay so what you do is make the gameobject static too, and then before calling the function where your gameobject is instantiated (your static string function) you initialize the gameobjects like so
        'gameObjectToBeInstantiated = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Cube");'

Why are you using statics though?

Comment: Well I have tried the same code; else {
    output += rolls[i].ToString();      // Normal 1-9 bowl

    strike = Resources.Load<GameObject>("GameOver");
    
    Debug.LogError("Try Your Hard");
   }
code is working without error but its not calling that prefeb gameobject or gameobject
would please write the code so i know how exactly it is.

Comment: Well the issue is solved:
public static GameObject strike, spare, gameOver, betterLuck; void Start () {
  strike = this.strikeObject;
  spare = this.spareObject;
  gameOver = this.gameOverObject;
  betterLuck = this.betterLuckObject;
 }
But still I am not able to destroy the object 
Error: Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);